# How to fix 'Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined' error when using webpack with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, axios

I use axios to get information from DB. I get response from server in array:

[image: response]

My html tags:
[image: htmlTag]

Js code looks like this:

```
    data() {
        return {
            departments: {
                id: 0,
                name: "name of company",
                nameZod: "name of company dif"
                },
            };
       },
    created() {
        axios
            .get('/SomeController/Departments')
            .then(response => {
                this.departments = response.data;
                console.log(this.departments);
            })
        }
```

I get an error: Cannot read property '_wrapper' of undefined. Its very strange cause I use similar code in other module and it works correctly.

Comment: Can you please post the full error message including stack trace showing files and line numbers?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Maybe you have defined a function call somewhere (@click=something) and you haven't defined yet the function in methods. This happened to me, maybe it can be useful for someone

Comment: Precisely what it was. :)

Comment: This was exactly my issue. I had a typo in the  methodName inside the form <form @submit="methodName"></form>

Comment: Had the same thing, although error is not informative at all!

Comment: This was the reason for my error, when the missing function was being called in a umd component

Comment: Thank you, this was the issue in my case as well

Answer (score 9):

This error occurs when a `v-on:click OR @click` directive in the template is missing the function it's pointing to, inside `methods` in your component.

Example:

```
//template
@click="callAgain"
...
methods : {
  //no function called callAgain
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling some function in your component which is not defined in your component yet, Please check all of your functions in your component are defined.

**For Example**

You are using @click="something" but something() not defined in your component.

Comment: This is really one of the downsides working with vue. Actually I barely see any point in vue if not for the component strategy (which is provided for much better in alternative frameworks). Make a small unnoticable typo in an event assignment and you are in a pickle debugging since the exception and provided trace doesn't give you many hints. Had one used ordinary addEventListener paradigm you would have clicked on the exception and turned up exactly where the problem is in code.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to initiate your departments as an array like this:

```
    data() {
        return {
            departments: [
                {
                    id: 0,
                    name: "name of company",
                    nameZod: "name of company dif"
                },
            ],
        };
    },
```

Comment: @HormanLewis whether it works or not, you still need to do this because your template expects `departments` to be an array

Comment: I hit this today because I had written @click="methodname.prevent", where I should have written @click.prevent="methodname".

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, but with different reason (Vue + Vuetify.
@click function must be attached to btn, not icon like below.

```
   <v-btn fab small>
       <v-icon @click="sendMessage">send</v-icon>
   </v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check `Pause on caught exceptions` under `Breakpoints` in the sources panel.
[image]

Then you can see the `name` variable that caused the problem (corresponding to @`name`=an undefined method) in Scope-Local.
[image]